# Android GoogleMap v2 Custom InfoWindow Size

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm testing the `InfoWindowAdapter` providing custom content `View`. I've tried simply returning `new View(Context)` as well as inflating a layout with a specific size. Nevertheless, the InfoWindow that gets displayed is rendered (in what seems to be the same size) a huge display, much larger than the default InfoWindow size. I'm returning `null` in `getInfoWindow(Marker)` and my desired content `View` in `getInfoContents(Marker)`.

Answer (score 8):

I solved it like this:

```
  googleMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

  @Override
  public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {

    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

    // Inflate custom layout
    View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.marker_view, null);

    // Set desired height and width
    v.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_id);
    TextView alt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_altitude);
    TextView name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_name);

    id.setText("Marker ID");
    name.setText("Marker Name");
    alt.setText("Marker Altitude");

    return v;
  }
});
}
```

Good luck.